# Proving that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin^m(n\pi/2)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Proving that the sum

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin^m(n\pi/2)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$
>   When $m$=integer even number

I know that the $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ comes from $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ and I know how to prove it but I don't know how to prove the above sum  especially with the power $m$

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=2n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$. IOW, $m$ is a *positive* even number (that statement is false for $m=0$).

$$\begin{align}
s_{2n}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2n}{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}}{k^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2n}{\left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2}\right)}}{(2k-1)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2n}{\left(\frac{(2k)\pi}{2}\right)}}{(2k)^2};~~\text{(split into even/odd terms)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2n}{\left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2}\right)}}{(2k-1)^2}\color{red}{+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2n}{\left(k\pi\right)}}{4k^2}};~~\text{(even terms vanish)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2n}{\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\right)}}{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left[\sin{\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right]^{2n}}{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left[\cos{\left(k\pi\right)}\right]^{2n}}{(2k+1)^2};~~~[\sin{(z+\pi/2)}=\cos{z}]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left[(-1)^{k}\right]^{2n}}{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1^{n}}{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.~~\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2}) \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$

For even $m$,
$\sin^m(n\frac{\pi}{2}) = \begin{cases}
0 : n \text{ is even} \\
1 : n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$

So, we can rewrite this summation as:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin^m(n\pi/2)}{n^2} \\
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n)^2} \\
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2} \\
= \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
= \frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$

Answer (score 0):

observe that $\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ is always $0$ or $1$ or $-1$

Your sum convereges absolutely, so you can partition it into 2 parts: part where the numerator is 1 and part where the numerator is $-1$.

Comment: There are exactly $0$ terms for which the numerator is $-1$ because it's an even power.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Determine the expression $\sin^m{(n\pi/2)}$. From this point of view you can do some machinary work for solving the series.

After some calculations you get the series
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1-(-1)^k}{2k^2}$$

Finally you have to compute the series.
Maybe some Fourier series are useful or you are able to split the series in smart partial series.

Answer (score -1):

Hint : $\sin^m(n\frac{\pi}{2})= (-1)^{(n+1).m}$ or $0$ for $n=2k$

Comment: $$\sin^m(n \frac{\pi}{2}) \neq (\sin(n \frac{\pi}{2}))^m $$?

Comment: Im new here, didnt learn the syntaxs well yet

Comment: You don't need to use \$ sign multiple time,also multiplication sign is best written with $\cdot$ or with $\times$ for some other kind of multiplication.Also when you want to group objects you put it inside {  },things like powers ^ and indexes _.Actually here's a guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Well thanks for helping